# I need to show that this complex series converges in C

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

I, unfortunately, don't really know where to start. I know I can't use the ratio test. Should I try to split it up into a complex and a real part?

> [image]

*Translation*: Show that for all $s\in\Bbb C\;$ such that $\operatorname{Re}s>0\;$ , the series $$h(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left[(4k+2)^{-s}-(4k+1)^{-s}\right]$$ converges in $\Bbb C$.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Übersetze die Frage ins Englische und bitte schreibe mathematische Formelsätze mit [Latex](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Weitere Kommentare und Antworten bitte auch auf Englisch.

Comment: Es ist nicht zwingend erforderlich, auf dieser Website in englischer Sprache zu schreiben. Es ist empfehlenswert, aber nicht obligatorisch

Comment: Of course, writing in English is way easier that most of the site's member will understand the question...

Comment: Thanks for the edit!

Comment: This looks like an assignment or test question you're asking users here to answer for you so you get 5 poings?  That's cheating.

Comment: It was a question on an assignment where almost nobody had the right answer and because we don't receive any solutions I asked the question on StackExchange.

Comment: So no, I'm not cheating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some ideas for you:

First, observe that for any positive real $\;a\;$ , is we write $\;s=x+iy,\,x,y\in\Bbb R\;$, then

$$a^s=e^{(x+iy)\log a}=e^{x\log a}x^{iy\log a}\implies |x^a|=e^{x\log a}=a^x=a^{\text{Re}\,s}$$

Thus, we get that

$$=\left|\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left[(4k+2)^{-s}-(4k+1)^{-s}\right]\right|\le\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left[\frac1{|4k+2|^s}+\frac1{|4k+1|^s}\right]=$$

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left[\frac1{(4k+2)^x}+\frac1{(4k+1)^x}\right]\;,\;\;s=x+iy\;,\;\;x,y,\in\Bbb R\,,\,\,x>0$$

and observe this last series is a positive one...Try to get it from here now.

Answer (score 1):

One can use that $(4k+2)^{-s}-(4k+1)^{-s}=(-s)\int_{4k+1}^{4k+2}x^{-s-1}dx$ so

$|(4k+2)^{-s}-(4k+1)^{-s}| \le |s|\int_{4k+1}^{4k+2}|x^{-s-1}|dx \le |s|(4k+1)^{-\sigma-1}, \sigma=\Re s$

(since $|x^{-s-1}| \le (4k+1)^{-\sigma-1}, 4k+1 \le x \le 4k+2$)

This means that the series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty|\left[(4k+2)^{-s}-(4k+1)^{-s}\right]|$ is majorized by the absolutely convergent ($-\sigma-1 <-1$) series $\sum_{k \ge 0}|s|(4k+1)^{-\sigma-1}$ so we get absolute convergence for $h$